# Plupload HTML4 Add Files dialog not triggering in IE

Tags: jquery, plupload, html4

I'm using Plupload (jQuery version) with HTML4 for IE, and for some reason it's not opening the File Dialog when I press the Add Files button.

The Plupload container is placed in a dialog, and I call `.pluploadQueue()` just before I show the dialog, each time.

It works fine on FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Cause

> I call `.pluploadQueue()` just before I show the dialog, each time.

---

### The Solution

Apparently, Plupload doesent seem to fire the dialog if the Plupload container is hidden (`display:none`) while evaluating `.pluploadQueue()`

I had to do a `display:block` before calling `.pluploadQueue()` - since I didnt want to fade in my dialog till after the Plupload stuff was done, I simply set the containers `opacity:0`

***Long story short***: Make sure your Plupload container is not hidden when you call `.pluploadQueue()`

Answer (score 2):

After showing or moving the button, call `uploader.refresh()` to have the runtime shim update its position.