# Plupload, IE8 and HTML4 runtime not triggering add files dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I have a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898082/plupload-html4-add-files-dialog-not-triggering-in-ie) but sadly not the same solution.

I have a custom upload instance very similar to their [example](http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php) that works fine in FF, Chrome and IE9 but it simply doesn't work in IE8 (or at least the closest I can get to IE8: [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)).

The uploader appears to initialise and reports that the html4 runtime has been loaded but the browse button does not trigger the 'Add Files' dialog.

Initially it was because the input item was in front of the browse button but I have changed the z-indexes to make sure that the browse button is on top. The button now clicks but the dialog still isn't fired.

The container is visible before plupload is initialised.

Calling uploader.refresh() does not help.

In the same IE8 enviroment, plupload's custom example does work.

And now I've run out of other ideas to try, anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: from the IETester page, I can see that "Known problems and limitations : ... -The input type file is not working (the file selection dialog does not open) " Wouldn't it be the cause of your problem ?

Comment: I am currently having the same issue. If I find a solution I'll let you know. (Concurrently, if you found a solution, please let me know).

Comment: @rob-forrest i found the reason why i was running into what sounds like a similar issue. Please check it out - turned out to be a pretty simple solution for me, and my uploader now supports IE7/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @jbl, you were right. This issue was with IETester's limitations rather than an actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: my upload form's browse button also was not triggering the file browser dialogue. My issue was that I did not define the id of my uploader parent element in my uploader options. You can pass the id of the element as 'container' in the plupload options.

Before fixing, the initialization of my uploader was (in Coffeescript):

```
 options =
   runtimes: 'html4'
   browse_button: 'modal-browse'
   upload_button: 'modal-upload'
   filelist: 'modal-upload-queue'
   max_file_size: '10mb'
   url: 'upload_url.json'
   multipart_params: params

 @uploader = new plupload.Uploader(options)
```

My uploader is hosted in a modal element with an id of "image-upload-modal". The simple addition of `container: 'image-upload-modal'` fixed my problem. EG:

```
 options =
   runtimes: 'html4'
   container: 'image-upload-modal'
   browse_button: 'modal-browse'
   upload_button: 'modal-upload'
   filelist: 'modal-upload-queue'
   max_file_size: '10mb'
   url: 'upload_url.json'
   multipart_params: params

 @uploader = new plupload.Uploader(options)
```

Incidentally, this also fixed the flash runtime for my uploader, which was also crashing in IE.

If this doesn't solve your problem, I have seen that on other Q+A some people's solutions involved the positioning of the fake file input that the html4 runtime creates to handle file uploads, such as:

1. Fixing the position of the fake file input over the browse button, as the browser was positioning that element wrong.
2. Fixing the z-index of the fake file input compared to the browse button.