# plupload can't show well and maybe it's style conflict

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, plupload

I use pluploadQueue to upload files which all the function could work well except the showing, I think maybe it's due to style confict. I want to know, does anyone have meet this issue before that?
using **MVC** + **bootstrap modal** + **bootstrap dialog** + **plupload Queue**

I can't upload picture, how to get reputaton?

```
 var uploader1 = $("#uploader1").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes: 'html5,silverlight,flash,html4',

        url: '@Url.Action("PLUpload", "Document")' + '?hasModification=true',

        chunk_size: '2mb',

        //Allow multiple files
        max_file_count: 10,

        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters: {
            // Maximum file size
            max_file_size: '20mb',
            // Specify what files to browse for
            mime_types: [
                { title: "Allowed files", extensions: "@Model.PLUploadAllowedExtensions" }
            ]
        },

        // Rename files by clicking on their titles
        rename: true,

        // Sort files
        sortable: true,

        // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
        dragdrop: true,

        //// Views to activate
        views: {
            list: true,
            thumbs: false, // Show thumbs
            active: 'list'
        },

        init: {
            PostInit: function () {
                // Called after initialization is finished and internal event handlers bound. http://www.plupload.com/examples/events
                // The uploader must in html4 only mode be initialized fully before it's hidden: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898082/plupload-html4-add-files-dialog-not-triggering-in-ie
                // Prepare uploader
                if ('@Model.HasUploadFiles' == 'True') {

                    $("#hasChanged").attr('value', true);
                    $("#uploader1").show();
                } else {
                    $("#uploader1").hide();
                }


                //// Force resize function is not working. this is the fix for window size
                //$('#formID').css("overflow", "hidden");
            },
        },

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/plupload/Moxie.swf")',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/plupload/Moxie.xap")'
    });
```